# Read array inside array into table Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So i have an array of response from backend services as below (array inside an array), i try to figure it how to turn it into table but have some problem on the logic:

```
"data": [
            {
                "id": "63ad33c69acfa205d354256b",
                "material": "1000000000",
                "material_name": "SAMPEL",
                "plant": "K111",
                "type": "rm",
                "current_price": 7718,
                "price": []
            },
            {
                "id": "63ad33c69acfa205d354256a",
                "material": "1000000000",
                "material_name": "SAMPEL",
                "plant": "K109",
                "type": "rm",
                "current_price": 7718,
                "price": []
            },
            {
                "id": "63ad33c69acfa205d3542565",
                "material": "1000000000",
                "material_name": "SAMPEL",
                "plant": "K103",
                "type": "rm",
                "current_price": 37259,
                "price": [
                    {
                        "date": "januari",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "februari",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "maret",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "april",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "mei",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "juni",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "juli",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "agustus",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "september",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "oktober",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "november",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "desember",
                        "price": 37258.978184562315
                    }
                ]
            },
    ]
```

does it possible to turn it into table as below using material UI datagrid or similar table library?:
[image]

any help on this will be very helpful....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ChangeWithCode/datantable

Here I have implemented that you can have a look.

```
<div className="App">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">material</th>
          <th rowspan="2">material_name</th>
          <th rowspan="2">plant</th>
          <th rowspan="2">type</th>
          <th rowspan="2">current_price</th>
          <th colspan="12">Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>januari</td>
          <td>februari</td>
          <td>maret</td>
          <td>april</td>
          <td>mei</td>
          <td>juni</td>
          <td>juli</td>
          <td>agustus</td>
          <td>september</td>
          <td>oktober</td>
          <td>november</td>
          <td>desember</td>
        </tr>
        {object.data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{item.material}</td>
              <td>{item.material_name}</td>
              <td>{item.plant}</td>
              <td>{item.current_price}</td>
              <td>{item.material_name}</td>
              {item.price.map((obj) => {
                return <td>{obj.price}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but its that posbile to do it with library because i have to do server render when using pagination..

Comment: Which library can you please elaborate on more?

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#column-grouping this library...

Comment: any help on that? @Muhammad Qasim

Comment: You have to set up a structure of material UI and apply maps as i sent above and it will automatically create a table for you.

Comment: I need to understand MUI first as I haven't tried it.
But let me install it and give it a try.

Comment: kindly wait on that..

Comment: If you provide the MUI dummy structure I can apply the map for you. 
As I am never tried MUI.

Comment: hi can i ask u more question to this?

Comment: Yes please ask.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution using material table `import MaterialTable from 'material-table';`:

```
<MaterialTable
        columns={[
          { title: 'material', field: 'material' },
          { title: 'material_name', field: 'material_name' },
          { title: 'plant', field: 'plant' },
          { title: 'type', field: 'type' },
          {
            title: 'current_price',
            field: 'current_price',
          },
          {
            title: 'price',
            field: 'price',
            render: (rowData) => (
              <MaterialTable
                columns={
                  rowData.price.length > 0
                    ? rowData.price.map((el) => ({ title: el.date, field: 'price' }))
                    : [
                        { title: 'januari', field: '' },
                        { title: 'februari', field: '' },
                        { title: 'maret', field: '' },
                        { title: 'april', field: '' },
                        { title: 'mei', field: '' },
                        { title: 'juni', field: '' },
                        { title: 'juli', field: '' },
                        { title: 'agustus', field: '' },
                        { title: 'september', field: '' },
                        { title: 'oktober', field: '' },
                        { title: 'november', field: '' },
                        { title: 'desember', field: '' },
                      ]
                }
                data={rowData.price}
                options={{ toolbar: false }}
              />
            ),
          },
        ]}
        data={data}
        title="Demo Title"
      />
```

Comment: is that possible to do it wtih Datagrid?